# Asp.net EnableViewStateMac and malicious code [December security updates]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, security, viewstate

In the latest Asp.Net [December 2013 Security updates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/10/asp-net-december-2013-security-updates.aspx) Microsoft released a patch for ASP.Net - 'Insecure ASP.NET Web Forms (.aspx) configuration could allow remote code execution'. Related KB is [2905247](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2905247)

As I know ViewStateMac just used to be sure that this ViewState was generated by server, and not an attacker. But in security updates article they say:

> If a web developer sets EnableViewStateMac=false for any page in his
>   site, an attacker could leverage this to upload and invoke arbitrary
>   **executable code** within the context of the web service account. This is
>   an example of a remote code execution (RCE) attack.

For example if I disable EnableViewStateMac for some aspx page, how it allows attacker to execute malicious code in context of my web application? As I understand in the worst case an attacker can spoof ViewState for some fake data\events\validation. But it will affect just this page. And I can't upload any malicious C# code via ViewState that will be executed. What are they mean by RCE attack in that case?

Comment: This could happen if framework code does something like reflection or disk IO based on ViewState.

Comment: hm, it makes sense, but it would be strange if Reflection is used for ViewState. I've checked source of some typical controls like Button, parts of GridView, Repeater, DropDownList, and seems they are not use reflection. But if they do, this problem should appeared before like in .Net 1.1\2, as ViewState doesn't changed too much since that time

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any further details of this vulnerability, so my answer only speculates to a possible attack vector.

The MAC is a signature of the ViewState value, and with `EnableViewStateMac=true` ASP.NET will check whether the MAC signature actually signs the ViewState value as authentic. This means that the ViewState value sent from the client in the `__VIEWSTATE` hidden field has been verified to come from the server.

Now imagine that the code processing the ViewState value is vulnerable to say object deserialisation. The Microsoft advisory states:

> An unauthenticated attacker could send specially crafted HTTP content to the targeted server, potentially allowing the attacker to run code on the server in the context of the service account running on the ASP.NET site.

With `EnableViewStateMac=true` this vulnerability cannot be exploited because the MAC is validated before the ViewState value is processed. Any value that has not come from the server will be met with a `Validation of viewstate MAC failed` exception message.

However, with `EnableViewStateMac=false` the whole ViewState value could be manipulated by an attacker to exploit the [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)/escape attack with [privilege escalation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) and execute arbitrary code that is injected as a payload into the `__VIEWSTATE` field.

So in summary, as the ViewState value is no longer being validated it opens up the field to attack by this unpublicised attack vector.

Comment: The buffer overflow was an example - it could be any vulnerability that could happen by a malicious ViewState value that would otherwise be protected against by the MAC.

Answer (score 0):

By itself, it doesn't necessarily allow an attacker to run code, but if you act upon some input expecting it to be valid -- hidden field with values or something similar, then it could be the key they need.

Comment: What specific quotes/sources are you basing this answer on?

Comment: even in that case, if I have input field and treat it's value as C# code, compile it on web site side and execute, then I agree it can be used for RCE attack, but I haven't seen such case in real applications. so I suppose MS is talking about something other...

Comment: @MartinSmith: at the time, none, just knowledge of what it does.  Didn't take much to find: http://blogs.technet.com/b/msrc/archive/2013/12/10/omphaloskepsis-and-the-december-2013-security-update-release.aspx which states that they aren't fixing buggy code.  Which means that any remote code execution wouldn't be their fault, which in turn means that any rce would have to be due to a bug/behavior of the web app (which goes with it executing as the web service account).

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov: not necessarily compiling it on the web server.  But it's quite common for a variable's value to go from the server->client->server.  Without verification that the value is good, that becomes: server -> whatever attacker wants -> server.  Whether that allows code execution or not will depend upon what the web app does.  But consider a Server.Transfer and an app that allows uploads...